# VB pop color picker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling

I have a question of VB event handler and color picker.

Now I have a label, and I want when user click it, it pops up a color picker dialog and let user to change the background color of the label.

Not sure how to implement this, can anyone give me a direction?

Thank you

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone?  ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: @SLaks most basic windows form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the .NET Framework's `ColorDialog` class in your `Label`'s click handler.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
     Handles Label1.Click  

    Dim cDialog As New ColorDialog()
    cDialog.Color = Label1.BackColor ' initial selection is current color.

    If (cDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Label1.BackColor = cDialog.Color ' update with user selected color.
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

here is the way to do it:

```
    ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
    paperLabel.BackColor = Me.ColorDialog1.color
```